# How to format from SqlDataReader string to currency format in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string-formatting

I retrieve value from database like this `173557.0000`. I want to display like `1,73,557.00`.

This is my code what tried

```
Table1001Hour.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text = rd["hour"].ToString();
Table1001Hour.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text = string.Format("{0:C}", Convert.ToInt32(rd["salesCost"].ToString()));
```

But it throws an error message.

> Input string was not in a correct format.

If I don't convert to string it shows like same as it is `173557.0000`

Thanks

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(rd["salesCost"].ToString())` why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It  looks like  the  problem is here:

```
Convert.ToInt32(rd["salesCost"].ToString())
```

So... don't do that? The  data coming back from the database  is probably *just  an `int`*, so: `(int)rd["salesCost"]` (or, if you're unsure of the specific type, `Convert.ToInt32(rd["salesCost"])`) should be fine. You could also then use the overload `ToString`; giving you:

```
Table1001Hour.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text = ((int)rd["salesCost"]).ToString("C");
```

(although  based on the  `.0000`, it could be  `decimal` or `double` - the latter of which would be  a very bad choice for financial data)

To be honest, I think it is a mistake to have UI code and DB code touching each-other  directly, but that might just  be me. If it were me, I'd be populating an object model from the database, and *separately* writing the object  model to the UI.

Comment: it's in money datatype in Sql Server. So when I retrieve the data it shows `1213.0000` in this format. your code is shows an error messae `specified cast is not valid`

Comment: it is not converting into either int or double. What should i do now?

Comment: @mohamedfaisal try `decimal`, otherwise: **find out  what  it is** - i.e. find out what  `rd["salesCost"].GetType()` returns

Comment: Yes i got the output. But result is like `123,235.75`. I want like `1,23,235.75`

Comment: @mohamedfaisal then  you'll need to pass in a `CultureInfo` into  the `ToString()` - presumably you want an Indian culture; for example:`var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-IN");`, `var s = (1234567.0M).ToString("C", culture);` gives `₹ 12,34,567.00`